# AspxClientPopupControl: CloseButtonClick and ValueChanged

Tags: devexpress

I am using DevExpress v10. I have an ASP.NET page with AspxPopupControl. The AspxPopupControl contains several textboxes AspxTextBox.

I need the following functionality: when user clicks Close button in header of the AspxPopupControl popup, to check if something has been changed in the AspxTextBox fields since the popup was opened. If it has, a confirmation 'do you really want to close the window without saving?'

I intended to implement it as the following: to handle client-side event ValueChanged for the AspxClientTextBox controls. In such handler I could set a flag, and later analyze it in client-side handler of Closing event (AspxClientPopupControl)

But the problem is: if I change something in an AspxTextBox and then click the Close button immediately, Closing event will be fired FIRST and ValueChanged event will be fired AFTER Closing!

This does not allow me to do what I want.

Is any solution possible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Closing` event receives as an argument an [ASPxClientPopupWindowCancelEventArgs](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxPopupControlScriptsASPxClientPopupWindowCancelEventArgstopic) which you can use to cancel the closing event.

You can do something along this lines:

```
<dx:ASPxPopupcontrol>
    ...
    <ClientSideEvents Closing="popup_Closing" />
</dx:ASPxPopupControl>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function popup_Closing(s,e)
    {
        if (textbox1.GetText() == '' || ...) // or logic here
        {
            e.cancel = !confirm('You've empty fields. Continue anyway?');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: yes, thank you.

you propose to compare 'initial' values of the controls with 'final' ones in the popup_Closing. yes, I thought about this. 
But I would like to know: is it possible to set some 'modified flag' immediately after a control's content has changed? To the moment I cannot resolve this problem. The controls has ValueChanged event, all right. BUT: suppose a situation when I change an AspxTextBox and then IMMEDIATELY click the Close button. In this situation I will first get Closing event, and only THEN ValueChanged event will be fired! This is not acceptable to me.

Comment: You can set that flag on `KeyPress` event. Or maybe textbox `LostFocus` event triggers before popup `Closing` event. There are a variety of options. You can even take another route and use Ok/Cancel buttons making popup's close button work as cancel.